# Parsing a file without BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been working on this small piece for hours now and couldn't find a solution, and it should be simple. This time, I'll post the actual code, and not simple examples, as somehow I can't get the examples to work with the real code.

I'm trying to do this with built-in modules (though if you have the answer using bs4 I'd like to know it as well). It should be a simple thing.

I have two files, an HTML file that goes like this.

```
<b>Match #139</b></font></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><td align="CENTER" width="10%"><font color="Green" face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><b>Yes</b></font></td><td nowrap="">&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3822pb01">3822pb01</a>&nbsp;</font></td><td><font face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><b>Door 1 x 3 x 1 Left with 'POLICE' Pattern</b></font><font class="fv"><br><a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalog.asp">Catalog</a>: <a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=P">Parts</a>:&nbsp;<a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catID=642">Door, Decorated</a></font></td><td nowrap=""><font class="fv">&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td align="CENTER" width="10%"><font color="Green" face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><b>Yes</b></font></td><td nowrap="">&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3821pb01">3821pb01</a>&nbsp;</font></td><td><font face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><b>Door 1 x 3 x 1 Right with 'POLICE' Pattern</b></font><font class="fv"><br><a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalog.asp">Catalog</a>: <a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=P">Parts</a>:&nbsp;<a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catID=642">Door, Decorated</a></font></td><td nowrap=""><font class="fv">&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#5E5A80"><td colspan="4"><font face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;<b>Match #140</b></font></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE"><td align="CENTER" width="10%"><font color="Green" face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><b>Yes</b></font></td><td nowrap="">&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3822pb02">3822pb02</a>&nbsp;</font></td><td><font face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><b>Door 1 x 3 x 1 Left with Classic Fire Logo Pattern</b></font><font class="fv"><br><a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalog.asp">Catalog</a>: <a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=P">Parts</a>:&nbsp;<a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catID=642">Door, Decorated</a></font></td><td nowrap=""><font class="fv">&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td align="CENTER" width="10%"><font color="Green" face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><b>Yes</b></font></td><td nowrap="">&nbsp;<font face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3821pb02">3821pb02</a>&nbsp;</font></td><td><font face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2"><b>Door 1 x 3 x 1 Right with Classic Fire Logo Pattern</b></font><font class="fv"><br><a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalog.asp">Catalog</a>: <a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogTree.asp?itemType=P">Parts</a>:&nbsp;<a href="http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catID=642">Door, Decorated</a></font></td><td nowrap=""><font class="fv">&nbsp;</font></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#5E5A80"><td colspan="4"><font face="Tahoma,Arial" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;<b>
```

Please don't kill me, yes, it's only a line. You can paste it into some code editor to see it in multiple lines. The file continues with more "Matches".

I want to do two things.

1st, I want to create a dictionary that will use the match number as it's index number. So, for example, it would be

```
matches = {'139' : 'etc', '140' : 'etc'}
```

And then, if you look at the HTML, after the first link after the Match, there is a part number, in example, the first one is 3822pb01. There are usually 2 part numbers inside a match, and I want to create a tuple inside the dict with those 2 part numbers.

```
matches = {'139' : ['3822pb01', '3821pb01'], '140' : ['3822pb02', 3821pb02]}
```

So far, I have been able to strip out the part numbers, or the Match #'s, but not correlate the part #'s and the Match #'s.

Could someone help me approach this? - it runs a little away from my current knowledge.

---

Here's the full HTML file - http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=eWWh4XfM - HTML doesn't have the best formatting

Comment: Why don't you want to do it with BeautifulSoup? Seems like the ideal tool for this.

Comment: Can you share a little more context here? It looks like you ripped part of this out of a table.

Comment: BS is a little (very) away from my knowledge too, I'm trying to learn to do a couple simple things to speed up daily tasks. However, I would like to learn too some day, and know just a little bit of BS, so if you have a way to do this with it, I'd be glad to hear it. I just don't want to go into their docs yet, and didn't want to sound like asking for someone to do things for me (I guess that's what I'm doing anyhow).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hello Martijn, I'll post the whole html file into a pastebin, thanks for your patience.

Comment: With a file like this, beautifulsoup will actually be an _easier_ solution than some contraption of string searches and (ouch) [regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/223424).

Comment: @9000: regular expressions have their place, just not in parsing the tags. :-) My answer below uses regular expressions to select matching rows and links, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes, regular expressions are fine when you are not parsing HTML with them, e.g. for filtering the results of proper parsing, as in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using BeautifulSoup:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

matches = {}
_catalog_link = re.compile(r'^http://www\.bricklink\.com/catalogItem\.asp\?P=')

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage)

for match in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'Match #\d+')):
    match_number = match.string.split('#', 1)[-1]
    matches[match_number] = matched_links = []
    # Find the parent table row
    row = next(p for p in match.parents if p.name == 'tr')
    # next rows hold the links
    for sibling in row.next_siblings:
        if sibling.name != 'tr':
            continue
        links = sibling.find_all('a', href=_catalog_link)
        if not links:
            break
        matched_links.extend(l.string for l in links)
```

This produces:

```
{u'139': [u'3822pb01', u'3821pb01'],
 u'140': [u'3822pb02', u'3821pb02'],
 u'141': [u'3822pb06', u'3821pb06'],
 u'142': [u'3822p03', u'3821p03'],
 u'143': [u'3822p24', u'3821p24'],
 u'144': [u'3822pb05', u'3821pb05'],
 u'145': [u'3822pb04', u'3821pb04'],
 u'146': [u'3822px1', u'3821px1'],
 u'147': [u'3822', u'3821'],
 u'148': [u'3189', u'3188'],
 u'149': [u'801a', u'802a'],
 u'150': [u'801', u'802'],
 u'151': [u'445', u'446'],
 u'152': [u'825', u'826'],
 u'153': [u'825p01', u'826p01'],
 u'154': [u'825p02', u'826p02'],
 u'155': [u'3195', u'3194'],
 u'156': [u'30231pb02', u'30231pb01'],
 u'158': [u'30230px1', u'30230px2'],
 u'159': [u'3936', u'3935'],
 u'160': [u'30355', u'30356'],
 u'161': [u'3586', u'3585'],
 u'162': [u'3933', u'3934'],
 u'164': [u'981', u'982'],
 u'165': [u'43369', u'43368'],
 u'166': [u'972', u'971'],
 u'167': [u'972pa2', u'971pa2'],
 u'168': [u'972p4f', u'971p4f'],
 u'169': [u'972p63', u'971p63'],
 u'170': [u'30073', u'30074'],
 u'171': [u'6128', u'6127'],
 u'172': [u'4466', u'4467'],
 u'173': [u'fabah1', u'fabah2'],
 u'174': [u'x46', u'x48'],
 u'175': [u'4181', u'4182'],
 u'176': [u'4181p05', u'4182p05'],
 u'177': [u'4181pb01', u'4182pb01'],
 u'178': [u'4181p02', u'4182p02'],
 u'179': [u'4181p06', u'4182p06'],
 u'180': [u'4181p04', u'4182p04'],
 u'181': [u'4181px1', u'4182px1'],
 u'182': [u'4181p03', u'4182p03'],
 u'183': [u'4181p01', u'4182p01'],
 u'184': [u'4181p07', u'4182p07'],
 u'185': [u'3195px1', u'3194px1'],
 u'186': [u'32190', u'32191'],
 u'187': [u'32188', u'32189'],
 u'188': [u'32527', u'32528'],
 u'189': [u'32534', u'32535'],
 u'190': [u'44350', u'44351'],
 u'191': [u'44352', u'44353'],
 u'192': [u'47712', u'47713'],
 u'193': [u'42061', u'42060'],
 u'194': [u'43710', u'43711'],
 u'195': [u'41765', u'41764'],
 u'196': [u'41748', u'41747'],
 u'197': [u'41750', u'41749'],
 u'198': [u'6565', u'6564'],
 u'199': [u'41770', u'41769'],
 u'200': [u'43723', u'43722'],
 u'201': [u'43721', u'43720'],
 u'202': [u'41768', u'41767'],
 u'203': [u'3069bps5', u'3069bps4'],
 u'204': [u'42061pb03', u'42060pb03'],
 u'205': [u'42061pb05', u'42060pb05'],
 u'206': [u'3005pb001', u'3005pb002'],
 u'207': [u'48288pb02', u'48288pb01'],
 u'208': [u'2582pb03', u'2582pb04'],
 u'209': [u'712', u'713'],
 u'211': [u'3039px17', u'3039px18'],
 u'212': [u'3037px5', u'3037px6'],
 u'213': [u'3037px3', u'3037px4'],
 u'214': [u'30249pb02', u'30249pb01'],
 u'215': [u'42022pb09', u'42022pb08'],
 u'216': [u'42022pb05', u'42022pb06'],
 u'217': [u'30647pb05', u'30647pb04'],
 u'218': [u'30647pb01', u'30647pb02'],
 u'219': [u'30647pb07', u'30647pb06'],
 u'220': [u'30647px1', u'30647px2'],
 u'221': [u'2744pb02', u'2744pb01'],
 u'222': [u'42061px5', u'42060px5'],
 u'223': [u'42061pb01', u'42060pb01'],
 u'224': [u'42061px1', u'42060px1'],
 u'225': [u'41748pb05', u'41747pb05'],
 u'226': [u'41748pb16', u'41747pb16'],
 u'227': [u'41748pb12', u'41747pb12'],
 u'228': [u'41748pb15', u'41747pb15'],
 u'229': [u'41748pb07', u'41747pb07'],
 u'230': [u'41748px1', u'41747px1'],
 u'231': [u'41748pb06', u'41747pb06'],
 u'232': [u'41748pb14', u'41747pb14'],
 u'233': [u'41748pb02', u'41747pb02'],
 u'234': [u'41748pb04', u'41747pb04'],
 u'235': [u'41748pb09', u'41747pb09'],
 u'236': [u'41748pb08', u'41747pb08'],
 u'237': [u'41748pb11', u'41747pb11'],
 u'238': [u'41748pb03', u'41747pb03'],
 u'239': [u'41748pb13', u'41747pb13'],
 u'240': [u'41748pb10', u'41747pb10'],
 u'241': [u'41750px2', u'41749px2'],
 u'242': [u'41750pb01', u'41749pb01'],
 u'243': [u'6565pb01', u'6564pb01'],
 u'244': [u'4864bp10', u'4864bp11'],
 u'245': [u'4864pb006L', u'4864pb006R'],
 u'246': [u'2362pb04', u'2362pb05'],
 u'247': [u'4215ap06', u'4215ap04'],
 u'248': [u'4215ap24', u'4215ap25'],
 u'249': [u'4215pb021', u'4215pb022'],
 u'250': [u'4215ap07', u'4215ap05'],
 u'251': [u'30117pb02L', u'30117pb02R'],
 u'252': [u'30117pb03L', u'30117pb03R'],
 u'253': [u'30117pb04L', u'30117pb04R'],
 u'254': [u'30117pb01', u'30117pb05'],
 u'255': [u'30116pb01', u'30116pb02'],
 u'256': [u'2468pb02', u'2468pb03'],
 u'257': [u'3245apx2', u'3245apx1'],
 u'258': [u'4070pb02', u'4070pb01'],
 u'259': [u'41855pb09', u'41855pb10'],
 u'401': [u'47847pb001L', u'47847pb001R'],
 u'418': [u'4460pb01', u'4460pb02'],
 u'419': [u'3010pb027', u'3010pb026'],
 u'420': [u'3010pb025', u'3010pb024'],
 u'421': [u'2341pb02', u'2341pb01'],
 u'439': [u'4286pb03', u'4286pb02'],
 u'440': [u'41748pb17', u'41747pb17'],
 u'472': [u'43710pb01', u'43711pb01'],
 u'473': [u'30363pb08', u'30363pb09'],
 u'474': [u'50305', u'50304'],
 u'475': [u'50955', u'50956'],
 u'512': [u'4286pb04', u'4286pb01'],
 u'546': [u'47397', u'47398'],
 u'572': [u'3193', u'3192'],
 u'598': [u'3933a', u'3934a'],
 u'606': [u'3822pb07', u'3821pb07'],
 u'620': [u'3939px1', u'3939px2'],
 u'621': [u'2431px18', u'2431px19'],
 u'622': [u'3069bpx57', u'3069bpx56'],
 u'643': [u'4215pb015', u'4215pb016'],
 u'678': [u'54384', u'54383'],
 u'680': [u'42061pb06', u'42060pb06'],
 u'681': [u'42061pb02', u'42060pb02'],
 u'682': [u'41748pb18', u'41747pb18'],
 u'683': [u'41768pb01', u'41767pb01'],
 u'684': [u'42061pb07', u'42060pb07'],
 u'685': [u'48933pb02', u'48933pb03'],
 u'686': [u'3622pb011', u'3622pb012'],
 u'687': [u'3010pb055L', u'3010pb055R'],
 u'688': [u'3008pb038', u'3008pb039'],
 u'689': [u'3822pb08', u'3821pb08'],
 u'690': [u'3822pb09', u'3821pb09'],
 u'691': [u'3822pb10', u'3821pb10'],
 u'692': [u'3189pb01', u'3188pb01'],
 u'693': [u'3193pb01', u'3192pb01'],
 u'694': [u'3193pb02', u'3192pb02'],
 u'695': [u'3195pb01', u'3194pb01'],
 u'696': [u'4864apx10', u'4864apx11'],
 u'697': [u'4215pb029', u'4215pb030'],
 u'700': [u'2362pb10', u'2362pb11'],
 u'701': [u'4286pb06', u'4286pb05'],
 u'702': [u'3678apb05', u'3678apb06'],
 u'703': [u'3678apb07', u'3678apb08'],
 u'704': [u'4460pb04', u'4460pb03'],
 u'705': [u'2340pb17L', u'2340pb17R'],
 u'706': [u'2340pb21L', u'2340pb21R'],
 u'707': [u'2340pb03', u'2340pb02'],
 u'708': [u'2340pb11', u'2340pb10'],
 u'709': [u'2340pb04', u'2340pb05'],
 u'710': [u'2340pb16', u'2340pb15'],
 u'711': [u'2340pb07', u'2340pb06'],
 u'712': [u'2340pb09', u'2340pb08'],
 u'714': [u'2431pb039', u'2431pb040'],
 u'727': [u'2431pb025', u'2431pb026'],
 u'728': [u'791pb01L', u'791pb01R'],
 u'766': [u'3004pb031L', u'3004pb031R'],
 u'768': [u'3010pb057L', u'3010pb057R'],
 u'769': [u'3009pb071L', u'3009pb071R'],
 u'770': [u'3009pb072L', u'3009pb072R'],
 u'771': [u'2873pb08L', u'2873pb08R'],
 u'772': [u'4286pb07L', u'4286pb07R'],
 u'773': [u'4286pb08L', u'4286pb08R'],
 u'774': [u'2340pb25L', u'2340pb25R'],
 u'775': [u'2340pb23L', u'2340pb23R'],
 u'776': [u'3004pb021L', u'3004pb021R'],
 u'777': [u'3004pb017L', u'3004pb017R']}
```

Comment: *baffled* Wouldn't it need to load the page first too into the program? And, it's giving me a `soup not defined` error, is that a need to use import - as?

Comment: @BrickTop: You did not share how you are loading the page. I'll add a line defining `soup`.

Comment: How could I write the output into a text file?

Comment: @BrickTop: Depends on what kind of text file you wanted to write.. But the simples way would be for you to just write `match_number` and `matched_links` on lines to an open file object.

Comment: It looks much better now, exactly what I needed! I'd just like to write it to an opened txt file. How could I do that? I put a `with open('test.txt') as file` before it, and now what to write it?

Comment: @BrickTop: I don't know, you tell me. What do you expect there to be in the text file?

Comment: Oh, of course, your code is to build up the dictionary, so I could essentially just post this code onto main app file and I will have the dict, right? What I was thinking is having a big text file with the output, to import and use as a dictionary on main app. I thought of this because it's not only one page where I have to build the dict with the matches, but there are more pages with further match numbers. I would apply your code to all the pages, and make one file with all the matches together, so I could use it as a dict on main app. Did I explain it?

Comment: You can easily save and load a dictionary like this with the `json` module. Read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), but `json.dump(matches, fileobj)` would write the whole dictionary to an open file.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on it, BTW, what's the meaning of the u's?

Comment: Allrighty, so exported to a dict and loaded, how can I access the list inside the dict? What I mean is, take the match `u'142': [u'3822p03', u'3821p03']` Is there a way to see if a number matches the 3822p03, to see if the part I have has a match? I have an `if partNO in Similar[]` but I don't know what to put in the []

Comment: Why don't you join the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) instead of asking follow-up questions in the comments?